# How to do sets for my android workout application?

Tags: java, android, conditional-statements

first thanks to read this.
I did a workout app for my team, inspired by a yoga app tutorial. My problem is in the yoga app you don't have many sets, just one, and i would like to add sets. I tried to make a `for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++)` in my ShowExercises but it didn't work and i would like to have the exercise and the rest repeated, not just the exercise. 
Here is my code,

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.workout_sure.Database.SWADB;
import com.example.workout_sure.Model.Exercise;
import com.example.workout_sure.Utils.Common;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.List;

import me.zhanghai.android.materialprogressbar.MaterialProgressBar;

public class Daily_Training extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btnStart;
    ImageView ex_image;
    TextView txtGetReady,txtCountdown,txtTimer,ex_name,detail_text;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    LinearLayout layoutGetReady;


    int ex_id=0,limit_time=0;

    List<Exercise> list = new ArrayList<>();

    SWADB swaDB;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_daily__training);

        initData();
        swaDB =  new SWADB(this);





        btnStart = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnStart);

        ex_image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.detail_image);
        detail_text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.detail_text);

        txtCountdown = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtCountdown);
        txtGetReady = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtGetReady);
        txtTimer = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.timer);
        ex_name = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.title);

        layoutGetReady = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout_get_ready);

        progressBar = (MaterialProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

        //Set data
        progressBar.setMax(list.size());

        setExerciseInformation(ex_id);

        btnStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(btnStart.getText().toString().toLowerCase().equals("commencer"))
                {
                    showGetReady();
                    btnStart.setText("fini");
                }
                else if(btnStart.getText().toString().toLowerCase().equals("fini"))
                {

                    if(swaDB.getSettingMode() == 0)
                        exercisesEasyModeCountDown.cancel();
                    if(swaDB.getSettingMode() == 1)
                        exercisesMediumModeCountDown.cancel();
                    if(swaDB.getSettingMode() == 2)
                        exercisesHardModeCountDown.cancel();


                    restTimeCountDown.cancel();

                    if(ex_id < list.size())
                    {
                        showRestTime();
                        ex_id++;
                        progressBar.setProgress(ex_id);
                        txtTimer.setText("");
                    }
                    else
                        showFinished();
                }
                else
                {
                    if(swaDB.getSettingMode() == 0)
                        exercisesEasyModeCountDown.cancel();
                    if(swaDB.getSettingMode() == 1)
                        exercisesMediumModeCountDown.cancel();
                    if(swaDB.getSettingMode() == 2)
                        exercisesHardModeCountDown.cancel();
                    restTimeCountDown.cancel();

                    if(ex_id < list.size())
                        setExerciseInformation(ex_id);
                    else
                        showFinished();
                }


            }
        });
    }

    private void showRestTime() {
        ex_image.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        btnStart.setText("Passer");
        btnStart.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        txtTimer.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        detail_text.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        layoutGetReady.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        restTimeCountDown.start();

        txtGetReady.setText("TEMPS DE REPOS");


    }

    private void showGetReady() {
        ex_image.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        btnStart.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        txtTimer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        detail_text.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);




        layoutGetReady.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        txtGetReady.setText("PREPARE TOI");
        new CountDownTimer(6000,1000)
        {

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                txtCountdown.setText(""+(millisUntilFinished/1000));
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                showExercises();
            }
        }.start();

    }

    private void showExercises() {
        if(ex_id < list.size())  //list size y'a ts les exos
        {

                ex_image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                btnStart.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                layoutGetReady.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                detail_text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                if (swaDB.getSettingMode() == 0)
                    exercisesEasyModeCountDown.start();
                if (swaDB.getSettingMode() == 1)
                    exercisesMediumModeCountDown.start();
                if (swaDB.getSettingMode() == 2)
                    exercisesHardModeCountDown.start();

                //Set Data youno

                ex_image.setImageResource(list.get(ex_id).getImage_id());
                ex_name.setText(list.get(ex_id).getName());
                detail_text.setText(list.get(ex_id).getDetail());



        }
        else
            showFinished();

    }



    private void showFinished() {

        ex_image.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        btnStart.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        txtCountdown.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        layoutGetReady.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        detail_text.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


        txtGetReady.setText("FINISHED !!!");
        txtCountdown.setText("Félicitations ! \n Tu as fini ton entraînement ;) ");
        txtCountdown.setTextSize(20);

        //Sauvegarder le workout de fou tavusa dans la db
        swaDB.saveDay(""+ Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis());
    }

    // Countdown

    CountDownTimer exercisesEasyModeCountDown = new CountDownTimer(Common.TIME_LIMIT_EASY,1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            txtTimer.setText(""+1/1000);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            if(ex_id < list.size() -1)
            {
                ex_id++;
                progressBar.setProgress(ex_id);
                txtTimer.setText("");


                setExerciseInformation(ex_id);
                btnStart.setText("Commencer");

            }
            else
            {
                showFinished();
            }
        }
    };
    CountDownTimer exercisesMediumModeCountDown = new CountDownTimer(Common.TIME_LIMIT_EASY,1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            txtTimer.setText(""+1/1000);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            if(ex_id < list.size() -1)
            {
                ex_id++;
                progressBar.setProgress(ex_id);
                txtTimer.setText("");


                setExerciseInformation(ex_id);
                btnStart.setText("Commencer");

            }
            else
            {
                showFinished();
            }
        }
    };
    CountDownTimer exercisesHardModeCountDown = new CountDownTimer(Common.TIME_LIMIT_EASY,1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            txtTimer.setText(""+1/1000);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            if(ex_id < list.size() -1)
            {
                ex_id++;
                progressBar.setProgress(ex_id);
                txtTimer.setText("");


                setExerciseInformation(ex_id);
                btnStart.setText("Commencer");

            }
            else
            {
                showFinished();
            }
        }
    };


    CountDownTimer restTimeCountDown = new CountDownTimer(10000,1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            txtCountdown.setText(""+(millisUntilFinished/1000));
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            setExerciseInformation(ex_id);
            showExercises();
        }
    };


    private void setExerciseInformation(int id) {
        ex_image.setImageResource(list.get(id).getImage_id());
        ex_name.setText(list.get(id).getName());
        detail_text.setText(list.get(id).getDetail());
        btnStart.setText("Commencer");

        ex_image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        btnStart.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        txtTimer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        detail_text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


        layoutGetReady.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);



    }


    private void initData() {

        list.add(new Exercise(R.drawable.test,"Positionne-toi face au sol, les mains hauteur d’épaules. Les jambes ne sont pas loin derrière. Rapproche tes jambes de manière à former un angle avec ton corps.\n" +
                "Ton dos doit rester bien droit et ta tête doit être dans le même alignement que ton dos pendant toute l’exécution du mouvement.\n" +
                "Descends en PLONGEANT EN AVANT tout en restant le dos droit  puis repousse fermement pour remonter.\n" ," Pompes Pike"));
        list.add(new Exercise(R.drawable.clappushups, "Mets toi en position pompe (dos droit, bien gainé, bras tendus), descends jusqu'à ce que tes pecs touchent le sol puis pousse de façon explosive de sorte à faire décoller ton corps loin du sol et pouvoir claquer dans tes mains.", "Pompes claquées"));
        list.add(new Exercise(R.drawable.dips, "En appui sur les barres, buste légèrement penché vers l’avant , fléchis les bras jusqu’à ce que ceux-ci se retrouvent à l’horizontal , puis pousse pour revenir à la position initiale.Reste toujours gainé.", "Dips"));
        list.add(new Exercise(R.drawable.diamondpushups, "Mets tes mains en prise serrée ou en forme de triangle, comme sur la video ci-dessus, fais ton maximum de pompes.\n Sans prendre de repos, écarte tes mains et fais ton maximum de répétitions. \n Enfin, reprends une prise basique avec tes mains et fais ton maximum de pomeps.", "Superset Pompes(Diamant-Ecartées-Basiques)"));
        list.add(new Exercise(R.drawable.jumpsquats, "Enchaîne un squat avec un saut.", "Squats Sautés"));

    }
}
```

My code with the for :

```
        if(ex_id < list.size())  //list size y'a ts les exos
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

                ex_image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                btnStart.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                layoutGetReady.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                detail_text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


                //Set Data youno

                ex_image.setImageResource(list.get(ex_id).getImage_id());
                ex_name.setText(list.get(ex_id).getName());
                detail_text.setText(list.get(ex_id).getDetail());

                showRestTime();
            }

        }
        else
            showFinished();

    }
```

Huge thanks, 
Stéphane

Comment: Where did you use for cycle

Comment: I used the for on the private void showExercises, below the first if

Comment: add showRestTime() at the end of for circle. But in the curly bracket.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer, I tried but when I add showRestTime() at the end of the for that repeat the showGetReady() and the showRestTime() indefinitely, and when I don't add the showRestTime it does not do anything, like the for doesn't exist  :/  I added my code with the for in the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read your requirements, As per your requirement you want to Show every set one by one and repeat them as well.

what you can do is create a `CountDownTimer` set time period to your each set then after completing one set, move to next one and when your setsList reaches to last one reset or repeat Timer.

**Sample Code**

```
  int counter=-1;

    CountDownTimer timer=null;
    ArrayList<Foo> setsArrayList=null;


    // foo is generic class(add your model for sets) , and setFoo is object that contains single set details. 
    void startTimer(Foo setFoo) {

      if(null!=timer){
          timer.cancel();
       }



    timer=new CountDownTimer(totalTime, setFoo.singleSetTime) {

         public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            counter++;

            updateUI(setsArrayList.get[counter])

         }

         public void onFinish() {
            //"done!" or repeat all sets if you want to
            counter=0;
         updateUI(setsArrayList.get[counter])
         }
      }.start();


    }
```

Comment: Oh thanks sir ! I'm gonna try it  ! Is there a way to repeat the set before moving to the next one please ?

Comment: yeah you can do it but showing somesort of popup if you want to repeat the resert it and start from first index.

Comment: in onFinish method if you want to repeat it you can show popup or button if user clicks on repeat then reset counter to 0 and update UI .

Comment: Hi, I was trying to use your code , then I realize that you need a specific time and I dont have it: Indeed, my CountDownTimer for the showExercises doesn't work (and I don't want to repair it it's better for me haha ) so the rest time displays when the user click on the finish button of the showExercises and he can click on this button whenever he wants. Is there a way to repeat a simple set x times automatically after the rest time pleasqe ? Sorry and thanks for the time you take for me

Comment: if you dnt want to add time.. then simply add next and reapet button on bottom of your UI on next increment the counter and on repeat play that set..

Comment: No not necessary

Comment: Yeah the repeat Button is a Nice way but how can I change it on next when the set is repeated x times? For example my first set need to be repeated 3 times and my second 2 times but how can I do that please? I know how to create the variable that define the number of sets for each exercise but not how can I change the repeat Button on next Button after the set repeated

Comment: all you have to do is pass object on next get next item and update ui on repate you can still re-use that set.

Comment: Sir, i'm sorry but I don't understand how to code this, maybe if you can code me a part of this so I may understand please i would really appreciate it ; or maybe help me with another solution that I've found (or maybe it's yours but i did'nt understand it  in this way lol), I'm gonna explain it with a comment below so that I can make some code

Comment: @swa_steph code is already posted all you have to do is use this code.

Comment: Yeah but I don't understand how to use it I'm sorry (so tired and exhausting in this time)

Answer (score 0):

I've added a string value in my initData() which is the number of the sets for each exercise (in other words the number of times I want my showExercises() repeated) and I want to add an int and if this int value doesn't correspond to the string add  int++ else just go to the other exercise 
For example, the string value set_number is 3, I want to create an int(or other thing, that's just an idea) which equals to 0. After the restTimeCountdown, if the int doesn't equal to 3, int++, else continue my code 
Here is the code I thinked for but it's missing the int configuration that I doesn't know how to do

The part of the startButton we need in this case with the modifications I thinked about:

```
                else if(btnStart.getText().toString().toLowerCase().equals("fini"))
                {


                    if(ex_id < list.size())
                    {
                        // Int configuration that I don't know how to do

                        if (int != //the set_number value we can recuperate with getSetValue but I don't know how to recuperate it in an int )
                        {
                            showRestTime();
                        }
                        else
                        {


                            showRestTime();
                            ex_id++;
                            progressBar.setProgress(ex_id);
                            txtTimer.setText("");
                        }
                    }
                    else
                        showFinished();
                }
```

the showRestTime:

```
 private void showRestTime() {
        ex_image.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        btnStart.setText("passer");
        btnStart.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        txtTimer.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        detail_text.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        layoutGetReady.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        restTimeCountDown.start();

        txtGetReady.setText("TEMPS DE REPOS");


    }
```

the restTimeCountDown:

```
  CountDownTimer restTimeCountDown = new CountDownTimer(10000,1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            txtCountdown.setText(""+(millisUntilFinished/1000));
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {

            setExerciseInformation(ex_id);
            showExercises();
        }
    };
```

The entire code is on my post, Thanks a lot